# Cakephp Input Select Multiple Selected problems with selected

Tags: php, cakephp, html-select

Im having some basic problems with that

```
    echo $this->Form->select('Already.alredyselected',$listnom,array(
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'label' => 'Text Label',
        'selected' => $alreadyinvites,
        'class' => 'selbox'));
```

My arrays are:

```
   $alreadyinvites =  Array(
[258] => Banana Voadora
[196] => Jack Bob Rodrigo Silva Junior)
```

and:

```
     $listnom = Array(
[258] => Banana Voadora
[196] => Jack Bob Rodrigo Silva Junior
[259] => Toucinho Defumado
```

)

but the CakePHP 2.4 or 2.3.2 arent printing the Selected on checkbox, What im doing wrong ?

Comment: Pass the selected values down from the controller via request->data - That is the cleanes approach. selected/value keys will break your form on invalidation/post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$alreadyinvites = array(258, 196);
```

and

```
echo $this->Form->select('Already.alredyselected',$listnom,array(
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'label' => 'Text Label',
    'value' => $alreadyinvites,
    'class' => 'selbox'));
```

Comment: Hash::extract($thiswavenominees, '{n}.Guest.id'); was returning values of ids as strings, not Int... i did a debug and found the problem. But thanks for the help !

Comment: I'm getting same issue in CakePHP 3.x, how to resolve same issue in CakePHP 3.0?

Comment: @yogeshsuhagiya maybe it's better if you post a new question describing your exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $selected = array(2, 3);
    $options = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

echo $this->Form->input('Attendees', array('multiple' => true, 'options' => $options, 'selected' => $selected));
```